# Is it safe to use block.timestamp when swapping erc20 tokens?

Tags: uniswap, decentralized-exchange

I have a swapping function in my smart contract and for the deadline I am using block.timestamp. The swap function can only be called by the owner of the contract. Is this a safe way of working with swaps? Should I use a different deadline?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It should be safe. All the contracts I've seen use `<= block.timestamp`.

If you are a little paranoid you could use `deadline = block.timestamp + some_value`. I've seen that snippet many times.